# In WPF, what are some controls which provide similar functionality to Popup?

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, wpf-controls

I have a WPF application and I have a search box of the top left corner of the application (which is basically a user control contraining a textbox and a button). I want the users to be able to press a shortcut key (like ctrl+Q) to make the same type of search box to appear in the center of the screen on top of the current window. I am reluctant to use a Popup though. Is there a control which could take the existing user control and make it appear in the center of the screen?
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need Adorners. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx

Comment: Thanks I will look into Adorners.